# Redirect non-existent subdomain to base domain url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I was using Droplr with my domain, 'example.com', prepended with 'u.'. (u.example.com). The prepend was not a subdomain, and would redirect to Droplr via an A record to their server's IP  Address.

Edit ---

In other words, I didn't create u.example.com as a subdomain of example.com, but rather created an A record to make it act like a subdomain.

However, I changed the domain being used with Droplr to example.com from u.example.com, and I am trying to setup a redirect with .htaccess to forward any requests to u.example.com/abcd to example.com/abcd.

I currently have the following, but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the domain. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^u.example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.u.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It might be because its saturday and I haven't had coffee, but this question makes no sense (among other things, `u.example.com` is ***by definition*** a subdomain of `example.com`).  I think you may just have your terminology tied up in a marvelous knot (confused between subdomain and virtual host?) -- can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: @voretaq7 Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: Yes, much more :-) And Kamil's answer below is the easiest solution (avoid the headache of mod_rewrite entirely wherever possible :-) -- If you want to do it with rewrite rules you can, its just more work -- [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as) can point you in the right direction

Comment: @voretaq7 I think that htaccess is actually the only way as I'm on shared hosting...

Answer (score 1):

Setup virtual domain u.example.com with alias www.u.example.com and inside the virtual server configuration do [permanent redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

You don't need mod_rewrite, it's unnecessarily complicated and demanding.

In case you have "wildcard" hosting for entire *.example.com you can use following rules to normalize your URIs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =u.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.u.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: I don't have access to setting up a virtual domain as I'm on shared hosting

Comment: If you're on shared hosting you're probably better off talking to your provider - they may have other restrictions in place that would cause you trouble...

Comment: Hmm, that's a good point. Is there any other way in which I could do this without having to go through virtual domains?

Comment: @iBeProgrammer and are you sure, the request ends in your current hosting? If so, see my edited answer